# Does placing order matter for IE conditional css and main css?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, cross-browser

Should it always come after main css or place doesn't matter?

**For example:**

if `DIV {width:500px}` is specified in main.css and `DIV {width:400px}` is specfied in IEonly.css which is inside Conditional comment.

Then is it must that, IEonly.css should come after main.css in source , or placement doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placement of style sheets always matters in CSS, conditional comments make no difference. If a style rule targeting an identical selector (*) occurs multiple times, the last one will take precedence.

So you need to include browser specific style sheets *after* the main style sheet, otherwise the main style sheet will overwrite the browser specific instructions.

(*) It's a bit more complicated when you have different selectors like `div.classname` and, say, `body.classname div.container div.classname` - then the more specific selector wins. More in the chapter "6.3 calculating selector specifity" in [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

Comment: ok thanks i thought main style-sheet will never override on browser specific style sheet.